# Get DataKey values in GridView RowCommand

Tags: asp.net, events, gridview, rowcommand, datakey

I have a `GridView` with an associated `DataKey`, which is the item ID.
How do I retrieve that value inside the `RowCommand` event?

This seems to work, but I don't like the cast to `LinkButton` (what if some other command is firing the event?), and I'm not too confident about the `NamingContainer` bit.

```
LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
int id = (int)grid.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Value;
```

I'm aware that I could instead pass that ID as the `CommandArgument`, but I chose to use `DataKey` to give me more flexibility.

I'm also aware that it's possible to use a hidden field for the ID, but I consider that a hack that I don't want to use.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I usually pass the RowIndex via CommandArgument and use it to retrieve the DataKey value I want.

On the Button:

```
CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>'
```

On the Server Event

```
int rowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
string val = (string)this.grid.DataKeys[rowIndex]["myKey"];
```

Comment: I ended up using the CommandArgument, but I can see how this solution would also work.

Comment: When I used a link rather than a button, I got this to work without setting CommandArgument in the aspx page. The CommandArguement property of the event arg contained the index of the row. I just used the code for the server event and it worked.

Comment: Vb Code:
`Dim rowIndex As Integer = Integer.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())
Dim val As String = Me.grdDatosPadres.DataKeys(rowIndex).Item("Field").ToString`

Comment: I just want to add that you can get row index like this without adding it to command argument " ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).Parent.Parent).RowIndex; " and use command argument for another data to be stored.

Comment: As an alternative, if you **do** prefer to specify a particular data item declaratively in the .aspx rather than "fishing" for it in code-behind, you can specify it like this in the .aspx: CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "cdbConsultantId") %>' and use it in code simply as e.CommandArgument (note that it is an object and you may need a cast depending on what you want to do with it). You may find this simpler and/or more clear in some situations.

Answer (score 33):

I managed to get the value of the DataKeys using this code:

In the GridView I added:

```
DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowCommand="myRowCommand"
```

Then in my row command function:

```
protected void myRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 
{
    LinkButton lnkBtn = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;    // the button
    GridViewRow myRow = (GridViewRow)lnkBtn.Parent.Parent;  // the row
    GridView myGrid = (GridView)sender; // the gridview
    string ID = myGrid.DataKeys[myRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); // value of the datakey 

    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
      case "cmd1":
      // do something using the ID
      break;
      case "cmd2":
      // do something else using the ID
      break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: when using multiple datakeys i suggest using : 
    string ID = myGrid.DataKeys[myRow.RowIndex].Values("ID").ToString()

Answer (score 12):

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvMyGridView.Rows)
{
    string PrimaryKey = gvMyGridView.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
}
```

You can use this code while doing an iteration with `foreach` or for any GridView event like `OnRowDataBound`.

Here you can input multiple values for `DataKeyNames` by separating with comma `,`. For example, `DataKeyNames="ProductID,ItemID,OrderID"`.

You can now access each of `DataKeys` by providing its index like below:

```
string ProductID = gvMyGridView.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
string ItemID = gvMyGridView.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString();
string OrderID = gvMyGridView.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Values[2].ToString();
```

You can also use Key Name instead of its index to get the values from `DataKeyNames` collection like below:

```
string ProductID = gvMyGridView.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Values["ProductID"].ToString();
string ItemID = gvMyGridView.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Values["ItemID"].ToString();
string OrderID = gvMyGridView.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Values["OrderID"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

you can just do this:

```
string id = GridName.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: No, that's not enough. The initial value of `CommandArgument` is not the row ID, it's an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

On the Button:

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("myKey")%>'
```

On the Server Event

```
e.CommandArgument
```