# How to get datakeys value in a gridview

Tags: asp.net

I try to delete a record in Gridview and Database .I added a boundfield button and set the CommandName to **Deleterecord** in the RowCommand event  I want to get the primary key of this record to delete that(primary key value does not show in the grid view. The following block of code shows this event(I try to show some data in a text box):

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.CommandName == "Deleterecord")
            {
                TextBox1.Text = GridView1.DataKeys[GridView1.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString(); 
                   //bla bla
            }
        }
```

I also set

```
DataKeyName="sourceName"
```

in the gridview but it is not my primary key

If I click this button an exception occured like this:
**Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index**
How can I solve this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get DataKey values in GridView RowCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818203/get-datakey-values-in-gridview-rowcommand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Deleterecord")
    {
         LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
         GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;

         TextBox1.Text = grid.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); 
         //bla bla
    }
}
```

Here `LinkButton` should be replaced by the type of control which is performing this `RowCommand` Event

For more info go [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818203/get-datakey-values-in-gridview-rowcommand)

Comment: Why what's the problem now ??

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'